# Remove a specific IMG tag from active html in a TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, dom, twebbrowser

I need to remove a little image from a website that I display in my TWebBrowser component in Delphi XE10 (VCL). I spend hours of searching and I tried a lot of code, but it is not working as I want.

This is a snippet of my code:

```html
procedure TForm16.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const [Ref] URL: OleVariant);
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  ElementCollection: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Frames: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Element: IHTMLElement;
  Frame: IHTMLDOMNode;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  ElementCollection := Doc.body.all as IHTMLElementCollection;
  Frames := ElementCollection.tags('IMG') as IHTMLElementCollection;
  if Frames <> nil then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Frames.length - 1 do
    begin
      Element := Frames.item(i, 0) as IHTMLElement;
      Frame := Element as IHTMLDOMNode;
      if Frame <> nil then
      begin
        Frame.parentNode.removeChild(Frame);
      end;
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Unfortunately it deletes all images. I want to delete a specific image that has a specific HREF. Can you help me with this?

Comment: You loop over them all, and delete them all. Why do that in if you only want to delete one of them.

Comment: thank's for reply .

Comment: I wan't to loop of them all so that i can remove the img node that has href='exp.com/exp.png'  but I Don't know how I can achieve it

Comment: Read the node's href attribute

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are after the `src` or `href` attribute.
I'll assume you actually meant `src` (I'm not aware of `href` usage with `IMG` tag). if not, replace `src` with `href` in the follow answer.

Basically your code is fine. you can check the `IHTMLElement` attribute e.g.

```
if Element.getAttribute('src', 0) = 'something' then ...
```

I suggest using `IHTMLDocument2.images` collection directly and `IHTMLImgElement` which has the `src`/`href` properties e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
var
  Doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  Images: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Img: IHTMLImgElement;
  Node: IHTMLDOMNode;
  Src: WideString;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Doc := TWebBrowser(Sender).Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  if Assigned(Doc) then
  begin
    Images := Doc.images;
    for I := Images.length - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      Img := Images.item(I, 0) as IHTMLImgElement;
      if Img.src = 'http://foo.bar/my.png' then // or "Img.href"
      begin
        Node := Img as IHTMLDOMNode;
        Node.parentNode.removeChild(Node);
        Break; // optional
      end;
    end;
  end;  
end;
```

Note that I'm iterating the DOM backwards

```
for I := Images.length - 1 downto 0 do
```

because if we need to remove more than one node we wont loose the next node index after removing the previous one.